# Rails 3: get route pattern for current controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is there a way to get the route pattern that was matched from the controller action? E.g. if I have the following route defined...

```
get '/foo/:id.:format' => 'foo#show'
```

... within the FooController#show action, is it possible to get a string containing the route pattern (in this example "/foo/:id.:format")?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. It's a bit of a hack, but here's what I came up with. Just add this to ApplicationController:

```
def get_route_pattern
  Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request) { |route| return route.path.spec.to_s }
end
```

Comment: I like it!  I added it to the controller as a helper_method and to my application layout as <%= debug(get_route_pattern) if Rails.env.development? %>